# Trouble interfacing hardware and reading data from a serial port with Mathematica

Tags: hardware, serial

I am trying to communicate with a device using a serial port to usb connection. I am using the following code:

```
dev = DeviceOpen[  "Serial", {port, "BaudRate" -> 9600, "DataBits" -> 8,
"Parity" -> None, "Handshake" -> None, "StopBits" -> 1}]
```

I am getting a device object which says connected. (See the image below). However, I cannot get the data from the device (a list of 32 integers) when I use `DeviceRead[dev]` or `DeviceReadBuffer[dev]` which yield `$Timeout` and an `{}` list respectively.

[image]

An implementation of a small python code using the serial library gives the following list of 32 integers as expected:

```
Serial<id=0x3845160, open=True>(port='COM4', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity='N',
stopbits=1, timeout=30, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
sutterMP285: get status info
(64, 0, 2, 4, 7, 0, 99, 0, 99, 0, 20, 0, 136, 19, 1, 120, 112, 23, 16, 39, 80, 0, 0, 0, 25, 0, 4, 0, 200, 0, 46, 1)
```

[image]

There is clearly something wrong with Mathematica or the way i am handling things. Can someone help? Thanks !

the python code can be found at the following link:
https://github.com/mgraupe/SutterMP285/blob/master/sutterMP285.py

Comment: [this test](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87732/5467) validates a large part of your serial link.

Comment: It might be this: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=143028.0 (see answer #5) http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=310096.0 (see answer #2)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and it turned out the problem was related to the serial communication DTR signal. If this is the problem, a solution has been posted to this related question: [Mathematica connection to Arduino *Micro*...any idea how to set DTR high?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135090)