# Mathematica connection to Arduino *Micro*...any idea how to set DTR high?

Tags: hardware, serial

According to my experience and to various information, such as

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=310096.0

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887615/can-not-view-serial-data-on-arduino-micro

...the Arduino Micro board will not write data to the host unless "DTR is set to high".

I have been successfully interfacing Mathematica with Arduinos (such as Mega), but am stuck with the Micro, because of the above issue.

Does anyone know how to set the DTR to "high" on the Mathematica side?

Are there any options to given in DeviceOpen when opening the port, to set the DTR to high?

Many thanks for any hint.
Ioan

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, a solution is to access the port through NETLink.  That allows setting the port's DTR Enable property as follows:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[]; (* if not already installed *)
ser = NETNew["System.IO.Ports.SerialPort", "COM5"]
ser@DtrEnable = True
ser@Open[]
```

You can then use the methods on the SerialPort object e.g. `ser@ReadExisting[]` to read from the port, or `serOnDataReceived = AddEventHandler[ser@DataReceived, onDataReceived]` to register a callback.

Comment: Many thanks. Precious input.

I will try this.

I just figured out what this syntax (@) means, never used it before. I actually will want to read from the buffer, as I need the last 16 values in there. I used to use (with other Arduinos, connected to by means of DeviceOpen[]), the expression 

values=DeviceReadBuffer[ArduinoData]