# Send serial input to Arduino Meta2560 board

Tags: hardware, serial

```
DeviceOpen ["Serial", {"/dev/cu.usbmodem1461", "BaudRate" -> 9600}]
DeviceWriteBuffer[serial, {3}]
```

Used the above code in an attempt to send {3} to Arduino Meta2560 through serial port and was unsuccessful. Please help. 
[image]

Comment: you may do [this test](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87732/5467)

Comment: Use the code block format to help do our own test.