# Send plain text out through a COM port (such as Labview, MATlab, Python or even a terminal emulator)

Tags: external-calls, process-control

We have purchased a pump. And we would like to control the pump through Mathematica. The furnished has explained to us:

```
The KDS 410 is not compatible with the Adagio software.

This pump can be controlled by sending it 'Pump Chain' commands (plain ASCII) from any application that can send plain text out through a COM port (such as Labview, MATlab, Python or even a terminal emulator)
```

I think that if Matlab can do this, so Mathematica can do it also. But I didn't find any command in Mathematica to do this. Can someone help me? Thank you very very much.

Comment: Look at the documentation for OpenWrite or OpenAppend for examples and the "file" you want to open is probably COM1 if you are using Windows.

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87732/5467)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wolfram Documentation has extensive examples of writing to serial ports

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/device/Serial.html

You would try something along the lines of

```
dev = DeviceOpen["Serial","COM1"];
DeviceWrite[dev,"Pump Chain"]
DeviceClose[dev]
```

(more details are needed about the baud rate supported by your device, specific commands, etc. to say any more, but this should at least get you started. )